# How to create new time entries in a pandas dataframe by linear interpolating

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe in hourly resolution as you can see in the screenshot[image]

So I have a temperature value for each hour of the day. Now I would like to increase the temporal resolution and have entries for every 15 minutes (00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00, 01:15 etc.). And for each of the new entries the values of the temperatures should be linearly interpolated.

Can you tell me, how I can do this by using pandas? I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Could you explain how the values for the temperatures are computed / selected for the intermediate 15 minute marks? Do you just take (row 2 temp - row 1 temp) / 4 and just add that to row 1 to obtain intermediate temperatures until row 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here’s one way:

```
df['Time (UTC)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time (UTC)'], format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
df1 = df.set_index('Time (UTC)').asfreq('15T')
df1.Temperature = df1.Temperature.interpolate()
```